# Git CentOS Vps: Make Repository from folder

Tags: git, centos, installation, vps

First, thanks for reading this topic.

What I want to achieve:
I want to keep track of what I edit (duh =]) on my vps but in the folder /usr/share/randomfolder/

Now after some researching I came up with the plan to install Git on the server, make a repository of the folder /usr/share/randomfolder/ so I can Fetch those files to GitHub and make my changes there. Once the changes have been made I can Pull the files back to the production server.

This would make it easy to keep track of the changes, and go back to previous versions.

What I have done as of yet: 
I have installed Git succesfully using Yum with the following code
`sudo yum install git`

And well, I'm stick at that point already! And now here I'm hoping that there is someone who can help me out on the right way or give a direct answer on what to do. Can you :)?

Ps. As you have probably seen already, i'm a total beginner with GIT

Ps. Feel free to correct me in anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a repository from an existing directory, you can simply run

```
git init
```

in that directory. This is enough to keep track of all your changes. You probably do not need a github remote repository at all. But you will need to invest some time to learn basics of git. Here is a good place to start:

http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2